# Facebook graph api posting over facebook users own page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook `graph api` page_id/feed. I successfully got post response but my problem is the post I shared showing over visitor post on Facebook page on which I am posting. I used manage_pages permission to get page_id of users pages.

```
 new GraphRequest( AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/" + page_id + "/feed",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "" + response.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
                            if (jsonObject != null) {
                                String postId = jsonObject.getString("id");
                                if (postId != null && !postId.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                    hideProgressDialog();
                                    Log.d("postId", "" + postId);
                                } else {
                                    hideProgressDialog();
                                    Utils.showToast(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.txt_try_again));
                                }
                            } else {
                                hideProgressDialog();
                                Utils.showToast(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.txt_try_again));
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            hideProgressDialog();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            hideProgressDialog();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use Page Access Token .Currently you are using User Access Token.